# How can I reduce noise from an air handler unit in an open closet?

Tags: furnace, noise, noise-reduction

How can I reduce the noise from an air handler unit?

I have a Goodman AR42-1 air handler unit in an open closet.  The setup looks like this:

[image: Air handler setup]

When the air handler activates it sounds like this:

https://youtu.be/XTcLtrniQB8

Current sound levels:

```
Everything off:           36 dB
A/C on and inside closet: 63 dB
A/C on with door closed:  59 dB
A/C on in Living Room:    55 dB
```

**Similar Questions**

[How do I reduce the noise from my forced air furnace?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58631/how-do-i-reduce-the-noise-from-my-forced-air-furnace) - recommends lining ducts with fiberglass

[Is there any way to make my furnace quieter without replacing](http://www.justanswer.com/hvac/4kfpb-furnace-quieter-without-replacing.html#re.v/184/) - recommends 1/2" rubber attached to the blower.

[Home Soundproofing](http://www.familyhandyman.com/smart-homeowner/home-soundproofing/view-all#step4)- recommends replacing a part of the duct with sound absorbing flexible duct or replacing a 6" section of the plenum with a rubber boot.

[sound reduction in a condo HVAC closet](http://forums.finehomebuilding.com/breaktime/construction-techniques/sound-reduction-condo-hvac-closet) - reduced fan speed, covered door except for vent with 1/2" of homastate.

Comment: It sounds like vibration noise, suck/blow noise and squeaky fan?   For the vibration you could try a rubber matt under the assmbly, if the entrire wall vibrates not sure you can do much with out a major rework.       The suck/blow. Does the lovred door being open closed make any difference to that noise... may be indicitive of not enough makeup air.   Squeaky, oil it?

Comment: Funny timing, I just moved out yesterday so I can't test any theories.

Comment: https://soundproofpeace.com/soundproof-water-pump/

Comment: 55dB is about the same as my dishwasher. Unless you're recording, odds are that if you gave it some time you'd brain yourself not to notice it. My boiler makes a bit of a thump when it ignites; seemed loud when I'd just moved in but I can't remember the last time I consciously noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have air handlers, but I am into audio.

Air going thru pipes is like a speaker. It makes noise. Make sure everything is tight. It may sound crazy, but I put a 2 inch plastic pipe to my ear and "pin point " where the noise is coming from.

Once all that is done, wrap the pipes.  Improves efficiency as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/163839)